# Windows: How to query state of modifier keys within low level keyboard hook?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, hook

For a usb keyboard configuration tool I need to intercept all keyboard input and detect which modifier keys and normal keys are pressed simultaneously. Therefore I use a windows low level hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) which works fine except that I´m not able to determine if WIN-Key (VK_LWIN / VK_RWIN) is pressed (control / shift and alt is working).

I made a little commandline tool to show the problem:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HHOOK hKeyboardHook;


LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if (nCode < 0 || nCode != HC_ACTION )
        return CallNextHookEx( hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    if(wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
        // working
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)
            cout << "CONTROL" << endl;
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000)
            cout << "SHIFT" << endl;
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU) & 0x8000) // ALT
            cout << "ALT" << endl;

        // VK_xWIN not working at all
        if((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN) & 0x8000) || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RWIN) & 0x8000))
            cout << "WIN" << endl;

        // working for ALTGR/right-handed ALT
        if((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) & 0x8000) || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RCONTROL) & 0x8000))
            cout << "LRCONTROL" << endl;

        // not working at all
        if((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & 0x8000) || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT) & 0x8000))
            cout << "LRSHIFT" << endl;
        if((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LMENU) & 0x8000) || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RMENU) & 0x8000))
            cout << "LRMENU" << endl;
    }

    //return CallNextHookEx( hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return 1;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0 );

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    return 0;
}
```

If I return "1" from LowLevelKeyboardProc every key press is "swallowed" (except for CTRL+ALT+DEL and WIN+L). If I call the next hook at the end of the callback function the behaviour changes (and the keys obviously aren´t swallowed any more). Then if WIN key is pressed together with another key I get the information that WIN key is pressed.

What do I have to do to intercept all keyboard input and detect a WIN-key press (using GetAsyncKeyState)? Or is there another way to get all (inkl. WIN) pressed modifier keys?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `LowLevelKeyboardProc` says the following about the return value:

> If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to 
>   prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook
>   chain or the target window procedure.

So, `return 1` says "I've processes the information, and there is nothing else that should be done with these keys".

I'm not certain how you fix the problem with detection of WIN key on it's own - I suspect the system just simply doesn't forward that has a keyboard event until the second key is pressed.

Comment: "So, return 1 says "I've processes the information, and there is nothing else that should be done with these keys"." 
That is what I want. I just wanted to show that processing the next hook somehow "repairs" the function. Perhaps someone else can use this information to find a solution for me ;-)

Comment: It's not "repairing it", the calling next hook will return the value from that hook - which is presumably 0, meaning the keys are processed by the system once it gets that far. If you return 1, the "next" process isn't being called, and the system discards the event because it has been processed. In other words, what you are seeing is exactly what you should expect to see. Or put another way, "it's not calling the next hook that alters the behaviour, it is returning 1". If you do `dummy = CallNextHookEx(...); return 1;` you will see the same thing.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But it doesn´t solve the problem. From the docs of `CallNextHookEx`: "You should call CallNextHookEx unless you absolutely need to prevent the notification from being seen by other applications." Thats exactly what I need. As a side effect it prevents processing the WIN key in a following hook (just a wild guess).

Comment: So, presumably you want to do this only under certain circumstance? So you shouldn't UNCONDITIONALLY `return 1`, but have something like "if (some_condition) return 1; else return CallNextHookEx(...);`

Comment: Yes, but I do it another way: my hook gets installed when a certain edit field gains focus (and uninstalled when it loses focus). So I don't have to decide within the hook and the hook chain gets a little bit shorter. (The edit field is used to display the pressed keys/shortcut).
Thanks a lot for your help, Mats.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out why I can't get the state of the windows key from within the hook, but I implemented a simple workaround which I don't want to keep back from you.

The callback function gets called if I press/release the windows key. So I just save the state of the key by myself and use this information on following key presses.

So the changed callback function looks like:

```
bool leftWinKeyPressed = false;
bool rightWinKeyPressed = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if (nCode < 0 || nCode != HC_ACTION )
        return CallNextHookEx( hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    // save state of win keys manually... (needs to be tested some more)
    if(p->vkCode == VK_LWIN)
        leftWinKeyPressed = (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)?true:false;
    else if(p->vkCode == VK_RWIN)
        rightWinKeyPressed = (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)?true:false;

    if(wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
        // not beautifull but working...
        if(leftWinKeyPressed || rightWinKeyPressed)
            cout << "WIN" << endl;

        // for example
        if(leftWinKeyPressed && p->vkCode == 68 )
            cout << "LEFT WINDOWS + D";
    }

    return 1;
}
```

To clean it up I will probably do this for all modifier keys and use a bit field to store the state of the modifier keys. So I'm not dependent on `GetAsyncKeyState` and it's weird behaviour. But if someone finds out why it behaves that way, please let me know.

Comment: How do you prevent the following `VK_LWIN` `WM_KEYUP` from opening the Windows 8 Metro menu? If I detect `VK_LWIN` `WM_KEYDOWN`, then the shortcut key, I have two choices: return 1 for `VK_LWIN` `WM_KEYUP`, which will result in every key triggering `WIN` key shortcuts, or returning `CallNextHookEx` which will open the Windows 8 Metro menu. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to this party, but CTRL + ALT + DELETE and other sequences are protected key sequences that cannot be intercepted or overwritten. There was some kind of way to do it back in Windows 7 if I'm correct, but to my knowledge there isn't one today, or it's really hard or considered a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, so gonna do some update from 2022.

I had the same issue and since we can't use API function `GetAsyncKeyState` inside the `LowLevelKeyboardProc` the only way I found is to write some custom code:

```
void SetModifiers(YOUR_STRUCT_TYPE* sStruct)
{
    // Get a code
    auto const code = sStruct->vkCode;

    // Check if key is a modifier key
    bool const is_control = code == VK_CONTROL || code == VK_LCONTROL || code == VK_RCONTROL;
    bool const is_alt = code == VK_MENU || code == VK_LMENU || code == VK_RMENU;
    bool const is_shift = code == VK_SHIFT || code == VK_LSHIFT || code == VK_RSHIFT;
    bool const is_caps_lock = code == VK_CAPITAL;

    // If the key is a modifier, then set it to `true/false` if the key is `DOWN/UP`, otherwise - ignore and keep prev state(if the key is not a modifier)
    // I use my custom struct here, but you can change it for global vars or something else
    sStruct->control = is_control ? !sStruct->keyUp : sStruct->control;
    sStruct->alt = is_alt ? !sStruct->keyUp : sStruct->alt;
    sStruct->shift = is_shift ? !sStruct->keyUp : sStruct->shift;
    sStruct->capsLock = is_caps_lock ? !sStruct->keyUp : sStruct->capsLock;
}
```

Not sure if it's the best one, but it does exactly what I want.